# Can SQLite be used for online databases?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I am new to this topic so my question will seem to be primitive for some people.
I would like to know if I can use SQLite offered in android to access online databases rather than create my own offline database?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

No, sqlite is only for local, embedded databases.

To access databases on the network you need to use whatever API offered, such as an web service API used over HTTP(S).