# How to: Android Quiz App, extracting da

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I'm looking to create a 'quiz' application that will have multiple categories, in those categories will be questions that the user will be able to answer in order and their progress will be saved. I want the progress to be saved locally so it can be used without the internet but I would also like to access some of the information that is being saved if possible, such as what users have completed what category?

I have Java and SQL knowledge but I'm pretty confused about the whole thing when it comes to adding them together.

Do I need to implement an SQLite database in the app to store progress for the users, as well as a regular SQL server that will store the required data online? I was hoping it would be possible just to use the SQLite database to do both of these but I've looked and I can't figure out if it is possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is an internal Android's database, to which only the user has access. If you have no prior experience with it, I want to mention that if you reformat the structure of SQLite, you will have to erase the app and install it once again as the onCreate() method is called only when the app is first opened.

For your question you can do so:

The user does not have to have internet access to pass the quiz, and every quiz result you can store in the SQLite. And you can simply add a statement that checks whether the user is connected to the internet or not. If he is connected, fetch all the data from the SQLite, make a JSON object form the data you got, and use Volley or Retrofit to send this data to a webserver through the REST Api which you should make. If you have any questions please ask

Comment: So do you not think I should use firebase like Curio said? What server would you recommend for storing the data?

Comment: You can use the google firebase. Check this link please:
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-working-with-firebase-realtime-database/

Also you can make your own web server, which will get http requests from your app, and will push the data to an online hosted SQL database. Please, if my answer was useful, mark it as accepted'

Comment: I have done sorry about that, I guess I'm just still confused because I've given a few options haha. I'm sort of panicking as well. I will have a look through this link and hopefully it will help

Comment: The best thing for you in my opinion, (both for functionality and for practice) would be to make your own REST API and host it online, as for example heroku. Read about REST API's! in some words: from android if the user is connected to the internet you will send the results in a JSON format to the REST API, and from the server-side, you just push that data in a database, let it be MYSQL or any other database. If you want we can continue the discussion in another place like for e.g skype

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the reply. 

Currently I've got some data going into as sqlite database. I've got logging on done through firebase but if I could pick your brain over Skype that would be awesome. Could you fire over your name through a PM?

Answer (score 0):

An SQLite database is only for local storage, meaning you won't be able to use it to communicate with other devices.

Here is a sample of my java and SQLite interaction

```
public List multiplyFat(){

String totalFat = "SELECT " + total + " FROM " + MyTable + " WHERE ( "
    + gas + " + " + shopping + " ) > 1200"; 

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
```

As we need to open a readable database session

```
List<Food> storeTotalFat = new ArrayList<>();
```

We create an array to store the data coming from the SQLite database

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(totalFat, null);
```

Treat the cursor as a means to lead the code through all the rows produced by the query above

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
 while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
  do {
     double fat = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(0));
      storeTotalFat.add(new Food(fat));
    } cursor.moveToNext();
  }
  cursor.close();
  return storeTotalFat;
}
```

Now when this method is invoked from another activity you will have a populated ArrayList ready to do whatever you want with.

**// now as to your question of which database to use**

As you want this shared database, you can use the [Google Cloud platform](https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/docs/).

I prefer to use Google Firebase but that works off of NoSQL meaning you have to query using JSON.

Comment: This sounds quite reasonable, is there much difference between google cloud and firebase? Do you have any links that would help me implement this ?

Comment: As for the difference between the two just go to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178919/google-cloud-datastore-vs-firebase). If you want a tutorial in Firebase, [this one](https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-cloud-backend-for-your-android-app-using-firebase/) is thorough and explains all the steps.

Answer (score -2):

Well, if you want to save LOCALLY your data, you need SharedPreferences (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). There is few data, so a database is wasted. Instead if you want an online database, you need Firebase for example. It's very good and give you other tools like the crash tool to know the crashes of your app in all devices (https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

You can use SharedPreferences to save the questions and Firebase to record the points and the names of all players for example. SQLite is only local ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/21599873/7339411), but not use it, you can do it with SharedPreferences, it's easier and faster.

Comment: So if I didn't want to store it locally and would be fine with it only being accessible when connected to the internet, would I only need a server such as godaddy? Is an SQLite DB needed for the questions or is there a simpler way of doing it? I've seen basic app examples that don't require one but as mentioned I would like to save progress.

Edit: Not too sure what firebase is for, storing a DB or not?

Comment: I see thanks a lot.

Edit: Does firebase use it's own language? I'm going to look at how to try and implement it into an app.

Comment: Looking at this has just made me a bit more confused haha, do you know any relevant tutorials that you think would help me?

Comment: @BlueBull Well, SharedPreference is really easy: you only have to read the paragraphs "Write to SharedPreference" and "Read from SharedPreference" of the first link. Just copy the code and use it when you need. Instead for Firebase I advice you https://youtu.be/0NFwF7L-YA8 and https://youtu.be/nxt93qyf7ec?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmxfvI4Ds2Atko79iVvxlaq. In this last the playlist isn't ordered

Comment: Thanks a lot I will look at them when I'm home.

Is Android progrmming similar to OOP? Will I need to make multiple java classes for each category? Sorry for all the questions I will end this soon :P

Comment: @BlueBull Don't worry ;) Yes, android is based on OOP because it is made in Java, but there are different libraries which give you activities, fragments and so on and you have to learn how use them. What do you mean for "multiple java classes"? If I understood well, it depends. You can adapt a class (fragment for example) to more situations.

Comment: Erm, for example, would I create a quiz class and use children of it to create the different categories?

Comment: @BlueBull  The quiz class (activity) is the box. In it there are the categories. You can access to a category by a button in the quiz class. Later there is the questions box (activity). Then the questions start. These ones always have the same layout, I mean a text (the question) and the checkboxes for example. This layout is a fragment. You only have to have 1 fragment class because you only have to change the question text. This fragment is put in the second box. The fragment is only one, but you can. use it multiple times and applying modifies too.

Comment: @BlueBull In this case you don't need OOP (according to the previous example) because all these classes extend another by default (activity,fragment) and you can't remove it (otherwise it isn't anymore am activity or a fragment). You can use interfaces to pass data from fragment to activity.

Comment: Of course, OOP is used by the system but in this case you don't need OOP like Cat extends Animal

Comment: Okay thanks for that explanation it helps clear stuff up.

I'm still a bit confused about firebase though. From what you're saying I can use it instead of a DB ? It will store user info such as email/password? 

I've looked through SO and most stuff about storing data is through mySQL so just trying to understand why you recommended it :)

Edit: Also - is firebase free or no?

Comment: @BlueBull MySql is only for local things. For example Pacman is offline. In Pacman you don't want to share your data, so you save it locally with SharedPreferences. MySql is for a lot of data (more of 1000 for example). Instead, if you want to share your data, you need Firebase. I think that you saw the authentication, not the database in Firebase. You need to watch that tutorial to store and share data. Firebase is free, but there is a payed version which gives you more functions like the device test.

Comment: Okay thanks again. I knew I could store data online with firebase, but I wasn't sure if me an 'admin' could access the data being stored by other users?

Comment: @BlueBull  Yes you can access to the data. For example you have to access to the max score. When the user opens the app for the first time, he has to insert his user name and it will be saved in the database. Then you connect the name with the score. The name is the box and you can give all user data to it which in firebase are called "children" but it isn't OOP there. So you can access all data-user with these boxes (username)